# Multiple plots in a single row

Tags: r, r-markdown

From [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/graphics-for-communication.html):

> To put multiple plots in a single row I set the out.width to 50% for
>   two plots, 33% for 3 plots, or 25% to 4 plots, and set fig.align =
>   "default". Depending on what I’m trying to illustrate ( e.g. show data
>   or show plot variations), I’ll also tweak fig.width, as discussed
>   below.

How do I put multiple plots on a single row, using the method described above? I could use a package such as [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork), but the purpose of this post is to understand what's being described above. The R Markdown below doesn't generate what I'd expect, two 'pressure' plots on the same row.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "April 2018"
date: "4/11/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Text

```{r pressure1, echo=FALSE, fig.width=6, fig.asp=0.618, out.width="50%", fig.align="default"}
plot(pressure)
plot(pressure)
```

```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE, fig.width=6, fig.asp=0.618, out.width="50%", fig.align="default"}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image: R Markdown multiple plots single row]

Comment: `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve got no idea why your code (or rather, the code from *R for Data Science*) is not working. But plotting different data makes it work for me:

````
```{r pressure1, echo=FALSE, fig.width=6, fig.asp=0.618, out.width="50%", fig.align="default"}
plot(cars)
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image: result screenshot]

Alternatively, it seems to be enough to just specify different parameters, e.g.:

```
plot(pressure)
plot(pressure, main = '')
```

The fact that inconsequential changes fix the output indicates to me that this is a bug in RMarkdown.

That said, the easiest, most controlled way is to put [`par(mfrow = c(1, 2))`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.3/topics/par) into the hunk directly before the plotting commands (or a ggplot2 solution such as faceting or {patchwork}).

Tweaking the alignment via the RMarkdown options can be tricky, due to spacing inserted by the conversion to HTML.

Comment: you're right, that's weird. I can leave `fig.align` in my chunk commands, and simply change the first occurrence of `plot(pressure)` to `plot(cars)`, and everything works properly. Perhaps you can't plot the same thing twice in a single chunk? Bug? Feature?

Comment: @JasonHunter Oh, I hadn’t even noticed that I still left that in. I only put it in for debugging but, yes, it seems to be necessary to plot separate data. Bizarre. Maybe due to the filenames that knitr generates for the plots? However, even renaming the variable doesn’t help, it has to be actually distinct data (or different options, such as seeing `main = ''` in one). I’m gonna go ahead and call this a knitr/RMarkdown bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify fig.show = "hold" along with out.width, as you can see here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figures-side.html